# I get a macro error in NASM: 'error: parser: instruction expected'

Tags: assembly, x86, nasm, x86-16

I keep getting the same error: `error: parser: instruction expected`
I get this error with the following line:

```
WSTRING 'MESSAGE'
```

My code is:

```
Bits 16  
call clear_screen  
WSTRING 'MESSAGE'  
jmp $   

%MACRO WSTRING 1  
     mov si, %1  
     call print  
%ENDMACRO
```

I've tried this and doesn't work either:

```
Bits 16
MSG DB 'MESSAGE',0
call clear_screen
WSTRING MSG
jmp $

%MACRO WSTRING 1
    mov si, %1
    call print
%ENDMACRO
```

Comment: You can use the actual code instead of the macro, and then you will see which of the two instructions is incorrect.

Comment: You'd have to do something like creating a variable in memory somewhere with `msg_str: db "MESSAGE", 0` and then do `WSTRING msg_str`

Comment: Please see edit

Comment: Please show us the entire file and make this as [mcve], not bits and pieces. The order you place things can be an issue.

Comment: For instance I hope your macro appears BEFORE you use it otherwise you'd get an error.

Comment: In your update, move you macro to the top of the file before you use it. That was my guess earlier.

Comment: Thanks! That helped me, but can you explain why it needs to be like that?

Comment: Because NASM simply requires MACRO's to be defined before they are used. Because it wasn't defined before used NASM thought that `WSTRING` was an instruction, and since there is no such instruction it exited with the error you got.

Comment: You also need to place the string and any data after the code, or it will executed as instructions which can cause you problems. Move `MSG DB 'MESSAGE',0` after `jmp $`

Comment: Ok, thanks! Done it!

Answer (score 2):

You cannot use a literal string as an instruction's operand. You can only use  string 's address. This means, you need to instruct the assembler to place that string somewhere, and then use its symbolical address.

Comment: NASM allows multi-byte character constants.  NASM in 16-bit mode assembles `mov si, 'MESSAGE'` to `BE 4D 45`, and warns `word data exceeds bounds [-w+number-overflow]`.  So yes you can use a quoted literal string as an immediate, but it gives you the bytes (in little-endian order, i.e. `SIL = M`), not an address.